# 2-D String Returning null value after returning from function(android)?

Tags: android, multidimensional-array, sqliteopenhelper

I am implementing SQLite in android to get all the rows data using 2-d strings. But the strings are giving me a null value except for the value of the last index

Code I wrote to get all the data of table

```
public String[][] getAllData(){
    MyDBHelper myDBHelper=new MyDBHelper(context);
    SQLiteDatabase db=myDBHelper.getWritableDatabase();
    String columns[]={MyDBHelper.UID, MyDBHelper.USERNAME, MyDBHelper.MOBILE,MyDBHelper.EMAIL};
    Cursor cursor=db.query(MyDBHelper.TABLE_NAME,columns,null,null,null,null,null);

    int index_username=cursor.getColumnIndex(MyDBHelper.USERNAME);
    int index_mobile=cursor.getColumnIndex(MyDBHelper.MOBILE);
    int index_email=cursor.getColumnIndex(MyDBHelper.EMAIL);
    Log.i("tag",Integer.toString(cursor.getCount()));
    String strData[][]=new String[cursor.getCount()][3];
    while(cursor.moveToNext()){

        int index=0;
        Log.i("tag",cursor.getString(index_username));
        strData[index][0]=cursor.getString(index_username);
        strData[index][1]=cursor.getString(index_mobile);
        strData[index][2]=cursor.getString(index_email);

        Log.i("tag",strData[index][0]+"data");
        index++;
    }
    return strData;
}
```

the code which called the method

```
public void getData(){
    String data[][]=myDBAdaptor.getAllData();

    Log.i("tag", Integer.toString(data.length));
    for(int i=0;i<data.length;i++) {
        //Log.i("tag",data[i][0]);
        String username=data[i][0];
        String mobile=data[i][1];
        String email=data[i][2];
        DataProvider dataProvider= new DataProvider(username,mobile,email);
            listDataAdaptor.add(dataProvider);

    }
}
```

**the problem**
Suppose the strData={{"abc","123","xyz"},{"efg","456","pqr"},{"mno","789","fgh"}};

after the execution of this statement
 data[][]=mydBAdaptor();
the value of data is printing
data[][]={{null,null,null},{null,null,null},{"mno","789","fgh"}}
why the value are getting null?
please help i am trying for hours but could resolve this bug.

Comment: I think you should use a list or an array of objects by creating a class for the element you're trying to get from your Database just to make things simpler. Using a multidimensional array for such a task is way too hard to mantain...

Comment: By "2D Strings"... you do mean bidimensional arrays, do you?

Comment: A question, what is the line "Log.i("tag",strData[index][0]+"data");" printing in the logs? is it showing the correct data?

Comment: @LuigiPower i just followed what you said and it worked like a magic:)... but still curious why it was not working for the string. yes it is printing data in getAllData()

Comment: Happy to be of help. I guess the problem was something regarding references, someone will be able to notice it and post an answer sooner or later.

Comment: @Rotwang there was no tag for 2-d strings

Comment: Because it's not a word.